# Restarting an Erlang node after a segmentation fault

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

I'm currently running an Erlang application that is running C code through Nifs. However, if a segmentation fault occurs within the C code, the entire node goes down, as well as the Erlang virtual machine that the Erlang application was running on.

What is the best way to monitor the Erlang application and restart it if the virtual machine dies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have a look at [Heart](http://erlang.org/doc/man/heart.html).

In addition if you have NIF calls that are considered dangerous it is recommended to isolate them together with Erlang code close to them on a separate node.  There are several ways of monitoring and restarting a node (e.g. [Slave](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/slave.html)).

Generally however I would advise against the usage of problematic NIFs, depending on for what you are using them there are more stable alternatives.

Reason for NIF -> replacement

Sequential speed -> better optimized Erlang code.  Often the high sequential speed of NIFs come at the price of them messing with Erlangs schedulers which often results in actual worse performance.

Interfacing with external libs/apps -> Erlangs ports are much better at failure isolation

Answer (score 3):

I've used something called [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). Some advantages over heart:

1. It's not erlang specific, so if you have other stuff on the same box, you can use it to restart things
2. Heart can have some [weird behavior](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-bugs/2012-August/003021.html) preventing crash dumps.
3. If you actually want to stop the erlang process for some reason, supervisord makes this easier.
4. If the segfault occurs at start up, [heart will continue to restart erlang infinitely](http://steve.vinoski.net/blog/2009/02/22/controlling-erlangs-heart/). Supervisord will stop trying to restart after a certain number of attempts.

Comment: And to add to this, `heart` actually failed to start my node correctly, using the same command line used to start it initially. Don't know why and I don't have time to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it Erlang way, you can go with any of solutions, mentioned above (heart, supervisord). If you want to do it Unix way, first you should make your Erlang app behave as Unix daemon.

Use [erld](https://github.com/ShoreTel-Inc/erld) for that. Next you can do a familiar thing: monitoring/restarting familiar Unix daemon.